# same DAX query resulting in different results

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

For a table (having 2 rows and 3 columns namely City1,Price1 & Units1) in power bi, I created a new column (named 'salesColumn') and a new measure (named 'salesMeasure) with the below DAX queries

```
salesColumn = SUMX('Table', 'Table'[Price1] * 'Table'[Units1])
salesMeasure = SUMX('Table', 'Table'[Price1] * 'Table'[Units1])
```

This resulted in the following visual:

[image]

As seen above, formula for both the column & measure are same but still they give different results. While salesColumn gives 6572 (12*175 + 18*229) in both rows, salesMeasure gives the row wise product. Can anyone please let me know why the behaviour is different in the two cases while we are using the same formula ? SUMX is a function to which we are passing the same arguments. If we are passing same arguments to a function, the function should behave in the same manner, but it is not so. Is there any hidden argument being passed to SUMX ? Can anyone please explain what is happening here & possibly paste some relevant links to understand this better ?

Comment: Cannot confirm why the second formula will return total of saleMeasure, I guess it is trying to evaluate the existing formula on it? https://dax.guide/sumx/

Answer (score 0):

This Two calculation should give you different output, the reason is that the SaleColumn are calculated only once at refresh time (The DAX expression defined for a calculated column operates in the context of the current row across that table.) --> you calculate a value for all rows (look at the summary from salesMeasure), while SaleMeasure is dynamic.

> Even if they look similar, there is a big difference between
> calculated columns and measures. The value of a calculated column is
> computed during data refresh and uses the current row as a context; it
> does not depend on user interaction in the report. A measure operates
> on aggregations of data defined by the current context, which depends
> on the filter applied in the report – such as slicer, rows, and
> columns selection in a pivot table, or axes and filters applied to a
> chart.
> https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/

Comment: thanks. above link says "The DAX exp'n for a calculated column operates in the context of the current row. **You cannot directly access the values of other rows.**"  

    here 'salesColumn' is a calculated column, it should be using the value of current row only but it is directly accessing the values of other rows (just opposite of what is told in the link above) and computing a value of 6572 which is the result of summation across all the rows. Why is that so ? How SUMX internally works ? It seems there is something else beyond just the arguments of SUMX (which are same in both cases).

Comment: I think that may be connected to internal engine operations. Filters always get applied first, then the evaluation is completed. (and you don't apply filter in CalColumn) Filters first, evaluate second. If you try 
salesColumn =  CALCULATE( SUMX('Table', 'Table'[Price1] * 'Table'[Units1]) ) You get exacly the same output as in salesMeasure.